# OpenCV python Stamp filter photoshop

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, photoshop

I am new to opencv. I have multiple images. One of sample image as shown below at top left corner. Basically I want to separate background and foreground so that edges are clear and I can detect contours properly.

I have tried many filter and of course thresholds using various parameters.

[image]

Finally when I was looking on photoshop filters gallery I noticed a filter called Stamp which is giving me desired result(top-right corner). It makes edges clear and I guess use some amount of blur to soft corners.

I am not sure how I can obtain same operation as photoshop's stamp filter using python CV2?

Any help or suggestions will be grateful.

**Original Untouched Image**

[image]

Attempt 1: -- Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

input_img = cv2.imread('images/Tas/t3.bmp')
desired_img = cv2.imread('images/stamp.jpg')

# gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)

thresh1 = cv2.threshold(input_img,80,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
erosion1 = cv2.erode(thresh1,kernel,iterations = 1)
dilation1 = cv2.dilate(erosion1,kernel,iterations = 1)

thresh2 = cv2.threshold(input_img,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
erosion2 = cv2.erode(thresh2,kernel,iterations = 1)
dilation2 = cv2.dilate(erosion2,kernel,iterations = 1)

titles = ['Original', 'Desired','thresh1', 'erosion1','dilation1','thresh2','erosion2','dilation2']
images = [input_img, desired_img, thresh1, erosion1,dilation1, thresh2,erosion2, dilation2]
for i in xrange(8):
  plt.subplot(2,4,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i])
  plt.title(titles[i])
  plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: It looks like a binarization, and probably erosion and dilation. Show the original untouched image also

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri Just added original image.

Comment: @AnderBiguri .. any help?

Comment: Yes... I already gave you. Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri . yes i tried and didnt get output required. I can attach image if you want to see.

Comment: Yes, show what you tried, that is a minmum requirement in stackoverflow

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri, i edit what i tried to my question.

Comment: It just looks like you need to adjust the treshold and erosion and dilation kernels. I suggest you stick with Otsus threshold level, then jus tplay with the erosion and dilation sizes.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I tried THRESH_OTSU along with medianBlur,GaussianBlur and adaptiveThreshold. I am not even sure if this will end up in desired result. I was looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276538/advise-filters-to-improve-text-visibility-on-photo/35279103 ... somewhere he says "then apply a stamp filter (a mixture of small Gaussian blur + threshold):"...

Answer (score 3):

It might help to add yourself a couple of sliders for Gaussian Blur and Threshold filtering and you can get pretty decent results:

[image: fake "photoshop stamp" filter with gaussian blur + threshold]

and here's the basic snippet I used to generate it:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# slider callbacks
def printThreshold(x):
    print "threshold",x
def printGaussianBlur(x):
    print "gaussian blur kernel size",x
# make a window to add sliders/preview to
cv2.namedWindow('processed')
#make some sliders
cv2.createTrackbar('threshold','processed',60,255,printThreshold)
cv2.createTrackbar('gaussian blur','processed',3,10,printGaussianBlur)
# load image
img = cv2.imread('cQMgT.png',0)
# continously process for quick feedback
while 1:
    # exit on ESC key
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

    # Gaussian Blur ( x2 +1 = odd number for kernel size)
    kernelSize = ((cv2.getTrackbarPos('gaussian blur','processed') * 2) + 1)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(kernelSize,kernelSize),0)
    # Threshold
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,cv2.getTrackbarPos('threshold','processed',),255,0)
    # show result
    cv2.imshow('processed ',thresh)

# exit
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Feel free to add other filters to the mix and experiment with sliders.

Comment: oh @GeorgeProfenza you are start mate. Thank you very much for taking time and doing this. Slider was really cool idea which i didnt think of. Main idea is to keep separation of upper and lower bone. I am sure gonna try some experiments on your code and will let you know in case i get result.

Comment: Sweet! If the answer was helpful feel free to vote/mark as you see fit ;) Have fun exploring filters. Looking forward to see what worked (might want to through [morphological filters](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) into the mix (you already had erode/dilate, perhaps open/close might help too)